# Web page not found of android app

Tags: android, facebook

I made an android app on facebook developers.com.
In the Mobile Web Url field I gave http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=352658298145952 which is what I wanted to be the URL of the app 
Now I am opening the app and it says Web Page not Found :/

Help is always appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile web URL is supposed to be the URL that your mobile website is hosted at. You've listed the old, deprecated, App Profile Page link - this will redirect to the canvas or website URL for your site.
Change the value to be where your mobile web content is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load Canvas Apps on a mobile device using this setting. You should link to a mobile version of your website instead.